# Reset dropdown menu using checkbox PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a function called `cek2()`. The function works like this, if checkbox is not checked it will reset the dropdown menu.
Here is my code.

This is my PHP code.

```
<?php
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "<tbody><td>Apakah <b>$r[nama_kriteria]</b> mobil sangat penting bagi anda?</td><td>"
        . "<select disabled id='bobot' name='bobot[]' class='bobot'>"
        . "<option id='kosong' value=0  hidden selected> Pilih Bobot</option>"
        . "<option value=1> Sangat Tidak Penting </option>"
        . "<option value=2> Tidak Penting </option>"
        . "<option value=3> Cukup Penting </option>"
        . "<option value=4> Penting </option>"
        . "<option value=5> Sangat Penting </option>"
        . "</select>"
        . "<td><input type='checkbox' class='kriteria'  id='kriteria' name='kriteria[]' onClick='cek();cek2();'</td>"
        . "</tbody>";
    }
?>
```

This is my Javascript code.

```
function cek2() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName('kriteria[]');
    var y = document.getElementsByName('bobot[]');
    var y2 = document.getElementById('kosong').selected = "true";
    n = x.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        y[i].y2 = !x[i].checked;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I just find a simple solution. Here is my code.

```
    function cek2() {

        var x = document.getElementsByName('kriteria[]');
        var y = document.getElementsByName('bobot[]');
        n = x.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (!x[i].checked) {
                y[i].selectedIndex = "0";
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You'll need to show some related HTML.

Comment: Posting code that appears to generate invalid HTML is not a substitute for actual HTML.

Comment: Thanks i just find a solution. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
function cek2() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName('kriteria[]'); // will give checkbox
    var y = document.getElementsByName('bobot[]');
    var y2 = document.getElementById('kosong').selected = "true";
    n = x.length; // you have only one checkbox with name 'kriteria[]' hence length is 1 , valueof n ==1
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) { // for (var i=0 ; i< 1 ; i++)
        y[i].y2 = !x[i].checked; // Hence loop will run only once
    }
}
```